# Join by time stamp within time period

Tags: r, dataframe, join, time, data.table

I have two tables, which I would like to join by date. If an instance falls within a color period, I would like that instance to receive said color as a variable (see joined):

```
instance <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID      UTC_DateTime            Value
1       2022-06-15 15:00:00     8
2       2022-06-15 15:05:00     3
3       2022-06-15 15:10:00     2
4       2022-06-15 15:15:00     4
")

periods <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
COLOR           UTC_DateTime          
Start_Green     2022-06-15 14:56:22
End_Green       2022-06-15 15:03:08
Start_Red       2022-06-15 15:03:11
End_Red         2022-06-15 15:58:48
")

joined <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID      UTC_DateTime            Value     Color
1       2022-06-15 15:00:00     8         Green
2       2022-06-15 15:05:00     3         Green
3       2022-06-15 15:10:00     2         Red
4       2022-06-15 15:15:00     4         Red
")
```

Also, if you could somehow incorporate a process which converts `periods` to `periods_wide` that would be great, see:

```
periods_wide <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
COLOR           UTC_DateTime_Start      UTC_DateTime_End
Green           2022-06-15 14:56:22     2022-06-15 15:03:08
Red             2022-06-15 15:03:11     2022-06-15 15:58:48
")
```

Please be aware that there might be many more instances and also many more periods (of the same or other colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `powerjoin::power_inner_join` and `lubridate`. Notice that `read.table` was not reading the data as intended and, therefore, I used `read.csv`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(powerjoin)
library(lubridate)

instance <- read.csv(header=TRUE, text="
ID,      UTC_DateTime,            Value
1,       2022-06-15 15:00:00,     8
2,       2022-06-15 15:05:00,     3
3,       2022-06-15 15:10:00,     2
4,       2022-06-15 15:15:00,     4
", strip.white = T)

periods <- read.csv(header=TRUE, text="
COLOR,           UTC_DateTime          
Start_Green,     2022-06-15 14:56:22
End_Green,       2022-06-15 15:03:08
Start_Red,       2022-06-15 15:03:11
End_Red,         2022-06-15 15:58:48
", strip.white = T)

periods %>% 
  mutate(COLOR = str_remove(COLOR, "Start_|End_"), 
         name = rep(c("d1", "d2"), 2)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(COLOR, values_from = UTC_DateTime) %>% 
  power_inner_join(instance,., 
                   by = c(~ ymd_hms(.x$UTC_DateTime) <= ymd_hms(.y$d2),  
                          ~ ymd_hms(.x$UTC_DateTime) >= ymd_hms(.y$d1))) %>% 
  select(-(d1:d2))

#>   ID        UTC_DateTime Value COLOR
#> 1  1 2022-06-15 15:00:00     8 Green
#> 2  2 2022-06-15 15:05:00     3   Red
#> 3  3 2022-06-15 15:10:00     2   Red
#> 4  4 2022-06-15 15:15:00     4   Red
```

Comment: Thank you @PaulS! Unfortunately, I get the error message:

Error: `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`

Comment: Have you tried with my dataframes, @Benisburgers? I guess you are using other dataframes...

Comment: I actually started a new blank script in an empty environment and simply copy-pasted your code. I'm surprised you're not getting the error I am. @PaulS

Comment: I have just tried and it worked perfectly, @Benisburgers. I guess that you need to update your installation of R as well as the packages you use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That's so odd. I reinstalled all the packages, I'm using a new blank environment and copy-pasted your code. And I also made sure I'm running the lastest version of R. Still, I get the same error. It's weird too, cause it only fails if I use both arguments for power_inner_join by(), if I only use <= ymd_hms OR >= ymd_hms, it works. Only when using both inn combination, does it fail.

Comment: Please, @Benisburgers, try my updated solution, which avoids `&`.

Comment: Thank you @PaulS! I'm afraid same issue: And when I use only one side of the coma, it works. Might it have to do something with the fact that if I use `~ ymd_hms(.x$UTC_DateTime) <= ymd_hms(.y$d2)`, I get 5 instances. And if I use `~ ymd_hms(.x$UTC_DateTime) >= ymd_hms(.y$d1))`, I get 7 instances?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245810/discussion-between-benisburgers-and-pauls).

Comment: I just ran it on a virtual machine and your code works perfectly! I will let you know when I find out what's wrong with my local version. Maybe it's a mac issue.

Comment: Great, @Benisburgers! I run Linux (Fedora 36), and it works fine. Maybe some packages were not updated -- you may have not noticed the error messages.

Comment: Hey @PaulS, so I just did a full-on update of all the packages and R as well, and now it works perfectly! Thank you kindly for all of your help :)